# wp_verify_nonce returns false on staging server but returns true on localhost

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to verify a very simple ajax request in WordPress (in order to diagnose a probem with a bigger form), and wp_verify_nonce keeps failing on my staging server, but on my localhost it works perfectly!

My setup is like this:

In my plugin __construct function I have:

```
wp_register_script('request-quote', plugins_url('scripts/request-quote.js', $this->root), array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('request-quote');
wp_localize_script('request-quote', 'pqimageupload', 
[
  'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
  'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'my_text' )
]);

add_action('wp_ajax_prq_checknonce', [$this, 'prq_checknonce'] );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_prq_checknonce', [$this, 'prq_checknonce'] );
```

Then in my request-quote.js I have this:

```
    $('#verify_nonce').on('click', function(){
        console.log('checking nonce');
        let data = {
            action: 'prq_checknonce',
            security: pqimageupload.security,
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: pqimageupload.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

My prq_checknonce function is:

```
    function prq_checknonce()
    {
        $response = [];
        $response['nonce'] = $_REQUEST['security'];
        $response['verify'] = wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['security'], 'my_text');
        $json = json_encode($response);
        echo $json;
        die();
    }
```

My HTML link:

```
<a href="#" id="verify_nonce">Verify nonce</a>
```

So it's about as simple as you can get! And when I click on the link on my local server: `http://abc.localhost/form/' the console log shows that`verify`is 1, however when I upload this to my staging server`https://abc.myserver.com/form/` console log shows verify as false!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Much appreciated
Lar

Answer (score 1):

Gaaahhh I'm so stupid!!! It was a caching issue, so whilst I was removing my temp files, I didn't delete my cookies... deleting my cookies did the trick!!